# Meaning of 抜ける in this Song

Tags: verbs, song-lyrics

So a song from Taiko-no-Tatsujin, おにぎりはどこかしら, is about a [girl] that needs more food, so she goes to a convenience store, and then comes back home and forgets the entire ordeal. She first wakes up:

> 昼だ起きよう／今日は日曜

> 学校ないよね？／あはは、気楽に

> ふかふかお布団／ぱぱっと**抜けたら**

> 大きく伸びして／おはようさん

I basically understand the entire song, but what exactly does 抜ける refer to? [looking online](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/#:%7E:text=%E2%97%87%E3%80%8C%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AF%E3%80%81%E4%B8%AD,%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%81%9F%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A8%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E3%80%82), I know it general means to come out, fall out, be omitted, and many other meanings. This is the intransitive form, so this is not something that the person singing did voluntarily. I tried to look up 布団 along with 抜ける, but I go nothing that made sense in the context, so I assume that something was omitted here; later in the song, they say "こもっている" without saying where one is stuffed up in, though the song clearly implies her house. However, not sure what 抜ける implies here. Any ideas?

Comment: It means simply *to come out*, or if anything, slipping out from 布団.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just "to go out (of somewhere)" or "to go through (somewhere)", and it's usually used with a tight space, either physically or mentally (e.g., トンネルを抜ける, 廊下を抜けた先の部屋, 嫌な会社を抜ける). A simpler way of saying this is お布団を出る, but saying 布団(を)抜ける conveys a sense of her diving into a broader and brighter space. The only thing omitted here is the particle を.